# Different between Amazon EC2 and a hosting website

Tags: amazon-ec2, webserver

Not sure if this is the relevant forum for this question, so just let me know if it's not and I'll move this.

Could somebody go over the differences between Amazon EC2, which I understand is a product that gives you access to a computer in one of Amazon's physical hosting location, and then allows you to add any kind of software you want (like MySQL, PHPMyAdmin, host websites, etc...), while a hosting site (e.g. goDaddy, BlueHost) basically does the same thing except these hosting sites do not allow you to install whatever software you want. Is this true?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another thing is to understand the larger goal of Amazon EC2 -- scaling. AWS makes it easy to scale-up new instances as traffic increases, then scale back down when traffic subsides.

But as to your original question, yes, you have root access to the EC2 machine. You can configure it any way you want, but you are also fully responsible for maintaining it.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. With Amazon [EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/), you have full control to a server (AMI - Amazon Machine Image). That means that you have to install and deploy any software packages to that server. With a web host you can install packages like MySQL, PHP, etc. with a click of a web button usually using cPanel.

The difference is that if you use EC2, you are in control. By changing variables like your database, server settings, memcache, HTTP accelerators, etc. you can improve the performance of your website. With a web host, you are at their mercy but you also pay for support. Security is up to you if you run a server on EC2.

I would start with a micro instance on EC2 and play around with it (it's free!) if you know how to use the Linux terminal. You can use [PuTTy](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) to access it via SSH.